Gitlab: does runner need to be same version as Gitlab server?
Online Gitlab version:
GitLab Enterprise Edition 17.5.0-pre c30a70942c6

Custom Gitlab runner version (running on Ubuntu):
Version:      16.1.0
Git revision: b72e108d
Git branch:   16-1-stable
GO version:   go1.19.9
Built:        2023-06-21T21:52:30+0000
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Just 2 days ago, one of my Gitlab CI/CD pipelines ran fine.  Today, several CI/CD pipelines have failed.  All concern compilation of Golang programs.
The change triggering the failure is tied to a version-specific dependency in go.mod.  Eg:
replace (
    gitlab.com/my-proj/common => gitlab.com/my-proj/common.git v0.2.29
)

where the version-update merely goes from, say, v0.2.28 to v0.2.29.
The error evidently is triggered when go attempts to retrieve v0.2.29 from Gitlab:
go: downloading gitlab.com/my-proj/common.git v0.2.29
cmd/server/main.go:14:2: no secure protocol found for repository

Others have reported the same error:  no secure protocol found for repository.  However, this error has not surfaced in our CI/CD builds during the last few months; then suddenly today, this error is triggered for several CI/CD pipelines.
QUESTION:  would a version mis-match between our custom Gitlab runner (16.x) and the Gitlab server (17.x) trigger this condition?

you seem to use replace to replace a module with itself. Have you tried upgrading the version directly ? module@v0.2.29 in the go.mod itself?

@LeGEC:  the point of the replace is so that imports in the Go logic can remain version-agnostic.  That way, if you have a dependency such as gitlab.com/my-proj/common/auth, you don't have to specify which version of common you require -- rather, it is implied by go.mod.

I'm not sure I understand your comment: modules in go.mod are already mentioned with a version number (note: the actual selected version may be higher if some dependencies require a more recent version of that specific module, but in that case the version number in your own go.mod would be updated by running go mod tidy), and no version number is mentioned when you write an import statement in a *.go file.

Do you observe the same issue if you simply mention gitlab.com/my-proj/common v0.2.29 straight in your go.mod file ?

@LeGEC:  I do that already, as someone else recommended that.  That is, I have the replace directive first (as per original question), followed after by a require directive that does what you said.

What you see seems to be triggered by having the old version in the module cache and not being able to download the new version.
Things you can try to diagnose the problem:

Is it a private module?

Check GOPRIVATE.

Can you access the module from the CI system?

Try git ls-remote https://gitlab.com/my-proj/common.git, also with git\+ssh:// and ssh://

Does it happen every time with empty module cache?

Try go clean -modcache. Caution: This slows down compile times.
Considering your replace directive: You don't replace something for version independence, instead you specify a different module name.
Every gitlab.com/my-proj/common version is replaced by gitlab.com/my-proj/common.git (note the appended .git in the name) version v0.2.29.
This is a work around for GitLab for packages that are in subgroup, I would suggest following the official documentation in “Use a project as a Go package” and authenticate Go requests instead.

I tried git ls-remote and confirmed repeatable error (no secure protocol found for repository).  Evidently, https-queries to our private repo with credentials set in ~/.netrc did not succeed after an upgrade (hosted, not on-prem, gitlab.com) from version 16.x => 17.x Enterprise.  I re-wired our Gitlab CI/CD pipeline to rely on git-queries through git@gitlab.com protocol -- using our private SSH key and published known hosts for SSH for gitlab.com. That solved the issue.  I consider this awkward behavior at best. CI/CD pipelines should not break as a consequence of GL upgrades.

@KodeCharlie Did you raise an issue with GitLab support? Since you are paying for GitLab Enterprise, they should be able to explain what happened...

It was a trial version.  And what a painful trial it was.
